# More efficient to loop inside switch statement or use switch statement inside loop?

Tags: java, performance, loops, switch-statement

(using java for reference)
I'm trying to determine which would be better, writing out more code and possibly saving some computing time or writing out less code but possibly sacrificing some computing time.
Here is what I'm curious about,
Would it be more efficient to do:

```java
switch (availability) {
    case "CASE A":
        for loop through hashmap Z:
              do specialized action a();
        break;
    case "CASE B":
        for loop through hashmap Z:
              do specialized action b();
        break;
}
```

or would it be better to do

```
for loop through hashmap Z:
   switch(availability){
      case "CASE A":
        do specialized action a();
        break;
      case "CASE B":
        do specialized action b();
        break;
   }
```

Just wondering if one way was better than the other? Obviously one uses more code, but does it have an advantage/disadvantage over the other?

Comment: Hey Reid, what don't you try and it and see?

Answer (score 2):

Approach-1 is better in terms of efficiency. Try to reduce the executions inside any loop iterations. In Approach-2 `switch(availability)` statement will be executed n number of times if the hashmap size is n. This additional cost will be high if the size of hashmap is very high in large scale applications.

```
switch (availability) {
    case "CASE A":
        for loop through hashmap Z:
              do specialized action a();
        break;
    case "CASE B":
        for loop through hashmap Z:
              do specialized action b();
        break;
}
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It's largely correct, and pretty standard advice.

Answer (score 1):

Unless this is a bit of critical code, I would optimize for readability and let the compiler optimize the actual code.

Usually the highest cost of a piece of code is in reading, understanding and improving/maintaining it. Execution is way less expensive, especially with cloud and growing computation resources.

I know this is not the answer to your question, but it's truly what I learned through the years.